# Phonegap remote build: where is the apk file?

Tags: apk, phonegap-cli

I'm using `Phongap v. 6` on `Windows 7 x64` for creating Android apps. I'm trying to build remotely in this way (obviously using a valid Adobe ID):

> phonegap remote build andriod

The process is successful but where I can find the apk file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are on the Phonegap Build server.

You have to download them from the Phonegap Build website.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your phonegap build account and click on apk button to download the apk file. You can also use qrcode on phonegap site and  scan it on your device to download the apk/ipa.